# IIS holding up requests in queue instead of processing those

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, iis-7, performance-testing

I'm executing a load test against an application hosted in Azure. It's a cloud service with 3 instances behind an internal load balancer (Hash based load balancing mode).

When I execute the load test, it queues request even though the req/sec and total current request to IIS is quite low. I'm not sure what could be the problem.

**Any suggestions?**

Adding few screenshot of performance counters which might help you take decision.

[image: #Processor Time]

[image]

[image: IIS counters - 1]

[image: IIS counters - 2]

***Click on image to view original image.***

*Edit-1: Per request from Rohit Rajan,*

Cloud Service is having 2 instances (meaning 2 VMs), each of them having 14 GBs of RAM and 8 cores.
I'm executing a Step load pattern start with 100 and add 100,150 user every 5 minutes, till 4-5 hours until the load reaches to 10,000 VUs.

Any call to external system are written async. Database calls are synchronous.

Comment: How many cores do you have in your azure VM. I see the CPU is 100%.What is the load test like,how many concurrent requests are you sending ? Can you add more details to the question on how you do the load testing,what is the load you are testing ? how many cores and memory you have for the VM,etc. Is your application written as Async

Comment: @hiren desai , what is the framework you are using ? , i'm assuming that you are using sessions and reusing the Session ID for your concurrent requests, ASP.NET will queue the requests because it needs an exclusive lock on the session for each request. try to change the default concurrent reuquest in the web-config

Comment: @Webruster, No we are not using sessions. Only 1 page of entire application uses session which isn't tested in this test.
"try to change the default concurrent reuquest in the web-config" what you meant by that?

Comment: @HirenDesai i mean to say you don't need to use session but  asp.net application will be running on session so i'm explaining that behaviour, for your second question please refer to the following [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/271124/what-is-the-default-number-of-concurrent-requests-that-can-be-processed-by-iis-7)

Answer (score 2):

There is no straight forward answer to your question. One possible way would be to explore additional investigation options.

Based on your explanation, there seems to be a bottleneck within the application which is causing the requests to queue-up.

In order to investigate this, collect a memory dump when you see the requests queuing up and then use DebugDiag to run a hang analysis on it.

There are several ways to gather the memory dump.

1. Task Manager
2. [Procdump.exe](http://live.sysinternals.com/procdump.exe)
3. Debug Diagnostics
4. [Process Explorer](https://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe)

Once you have the memory dump you can install debug diag and then run analysis on it. It will generate a report which can help you get started.

Debug Diagnostics download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924

Comment: To this, I'm having challenge in identifying when these requests are being queued up. The reason is, application is hosted in cloud (Azure) and knowing these counter for multiple instances at run time is a challenge. Anyway I'm still up to explore this option.
But do you think, this could be related to memory? I have memory utilization graph and I can see 20% utilization of it during entire run!

Comment: Without looking at the memory dump, I cannot say. 20% is normal. What does the Debug Diag analysis report tell you?

Comment: I haven't run it. It was just a question based on my previous result analysis. I'll post further sooner.